# How to check in JUnit what exactly value we are expecting to be returned?

Tags: java

In the example below, it could be checked that the last element of the sheet does not really appear, because it is already in the list. How can I check what exact value is expected to be returned?

```
public class streamExample2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    stringList.add("один");
    stringList.add("два");
    stringList.add("три");
    stringList.add("один");

    System.out.println (countstring(stringList));
}

    public static List<String> countstring  (List <String> stringList){
        Stream <String> stream = stringList.stream ();

            List<String>differentStrings = stream .distinct ()
            .collect (Collectors.toList ());

        return differentStrings;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement a JUnit test case? If yes, please show it here...

Comment: It's a lot harder to unit test a void method than it is to test a method which returns a value. I would suggest pulling the thing which constructs the value you want to test out into a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily test methods that have a return value using JUnit. Testing a `void main` is somehow harder and wouldn't make any sense in larger applications (those with more classes than the one containing the `main`).

In your case, I would extract the code to be tested into a method, let's say the following one:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StackoverflowDemo {

    public static List<String> getDistinctValuesFrom(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Due to this method being `static`, you won't need an instance of any class.

For a simple unit test — in general — you need an input value and an expected output value. In this case, you can implement two lists, one with duplicates and the other one that represents the expected result of eliminating the duplicates of the first list.
A JUnit test case compares the expected output with the actual one.

JUnit uses specific methods that compare (return) values (of methods).
A test class that tests this method may look like the following one:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import de.os.prodefacto.StackoverflowDemo;

class StreamTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        // provide a list that contains dpulicates (input value)
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("AAA");
        input.add("BBB");
        input.add("CCC");
        input.add("AAA");
        input.add("DDD");
        input.add("EEE");
        input.add("AAA");
        input.add("BBB");
        input.add("FFF");
        input.add("GGG");
        
        // provide an expected result
        List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
        expected.add("AAA");
        expected.add("BBB");
        expected.add("CCC");
        expected.add("DDD");
        expected.add("EEE");
        expected.add("FFF");
        expected.add("GGG");
        
        // get the actual value of the (static) method with the input as argument
        List<String> actual = StackoverflowDemo.getDistinctValuesFrom(input);
        // assert the result of the test (here: equal)
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Please note that you can and should test undesired behaviour, like false positives or `Exception`s, too. For anything going further than this simple example, google for JUnit tutorials and read some of them.

> Note that test cases may be wrong, too, which may cause serious trouble! Review your tests carefully because expected values may be wrong and thus a reason for test failing though the methods are correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by HashSet. HashSet is a data structure which stores only unique values.

```
@Test
public void testSalutationMessage() {

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    stringList.add("one");
    stringList.add("two");
    stringList.add("three");
    stringList.add("one");
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    stringList.stream().forEach(currentElement -> {
        assertFalse("String already exist in List", set.contains(currentElement));
        set.add(currentElement);
    });

}
```

Comment: Not a fan of this as there is no clear separation between executing the target of test and the assertion of the result returned by the target.  This makes the test hard to understand and to maintain, in my opinion.